# Printing Booklets on Canon ImageRunner Advance

Tags: pdf, printing, adobe-acrobat, margins

I am trying to print two booklets on my organization's Canon ImageRunner Advance, and both are coming out with uneven or excessive margins.

I am printing from PDF files opening with Adobe Acrobat Reader DC on a Windows 7.

One of the files needs to be printed on 8 1/2" x 11". I print it in landscape mode, fold and saddle stitch. The result is it consistently comes out with an inch of margin on the top and bottom of the booklet (if you are holding the book with the stapled edge to your left). It has the specified gutter on the left, and a quarter inch margin or little more on the right.

The second file needs to be printed on 11" x 17". I also print this in landscape, fold and saddle stitch. It comes out with 1 3/4" margin on the right, specified gutter on left, 1/4 inch or more on the top and about 1/16" margin on the bottom.

How can I get these margins to be even, or better yet, have no margins at all? (My margin options are greyed out, so I may not even have edge to edge available on my machine, but still, I should be able to get better margins)

Here is a screen shot of the basic settings:

[image: Basic Print settings]

[Here is the result I get when printing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WihA4.jpg)

Comment: Your screenshot does not depict a booklet, it depicts a single page sideways, but my first thought from the page depicted is that the margins come from the page being cropped to the "live area" for that printer. Most printers cannot print borderless to the edges since the feeding mechanisms need to grip the paper, and if we define "top" as the edge of the sheet as it enters the paper path, the "top and bottom" printable area margins are usually different.

Comment: @Yorik Thank you for your response. I managed to get the desired result for the 8 1/2 x 11 booklet by creating it in booklet form in publisher, exporting to pdf, and selecting "use application settings" in the printer options instead of "use driver settings." 

With the 11x17 booklet however, I still get too much margin on the short edges and uneven margins on the long edges. It doesn't seem like my printer can do edge to edge, but it should be able to do much less margin space than what I am getting on the short edges.